# Forbid merging a pull request to a branch if the PR was not created from it

Tags: git, github, bitbucket

The configurations of my application are kept in a git repository.

I use a separate branch for each environment e.g sandbox, UAT and PROD and they are completely different.

The problem is if a pull request branched from sandbox is mistakenly merged into prod branch, it will mess up the configurations there.

We enforce approval from reviewer for sure but to avoid any risk is there any way I can forbid merging a pull request to a branch if the PR was not created from that branch.

For example, if a pull request created from Sandbox, it will not be allowed to merge to UAT or PROD.

Comment: Pick one of the two hosting sites (Bitbucket or GitHub), because PRs are handled *by* the hosting site. They're not part of basic Git. Each hosting site does this sort of thing a little bit differently. You need instructions for your site. There are no instructions for Git itself. That said: there's nothing that records the creation point of a branch, in Git, so the information you seek is not available.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. My intent is not to use 2 different hosting sites and I think it'd be easier to use different branches in 1 repo. But it's not what I am looking for.

Comment: My point is that your question is not formed correctly: there's the Bitbucket way, and there's the GitHub way. Git itself [tag:git] puts some constraints on how either of the hosting sites will work, but any *rules* you establish will be specific to the hosting site you pick. So using [tag:github] *and* [tag:bitbucket] is inherently wrong here, unless your question is "does either site support this".

Comment: Ah sorry, I misread your comment. Currently I am using bitbucket and not yet find where this feature supported. Maybe there is an plugin out there doing the job?